# How to delete design configuration?

Tags: database, theme, configuration, magento-community, design

How to delete design configuration?

[image]

Comment: you to want delete theme ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no provision to delete these from admin panel.

The screenshot you shared is loaded from `design_config_grid_flat` table. You can delete entries from there.

If you wanna delete any theme then follow the steps.

**STEP 1** : Goto `theme` table and delete the entry for your created theme, remember the deleted `theme_id`.

**STEP 2** : Now goto `core_config_data` table and look for path **design/theme/theme_id** using your deleted `theme_id`. Remove it as well.

Run the following commands.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much!